Angular 18 NGRX 18, how to register a DataService which extends DefaultDataService to override GetAll function, in a standalone configuration?
I created a custom DataService ngrx/entity that extends the NGRX DefaultDataService, I need to get to a custom URL which returns a Json Object.  However I haven't been able to register my Custom DataService as I have no modules installed and haven't found any way to register the service so the override never happens.  Anyone else having this issue?
Installed:
    "@angular/animations": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^18.2.0",
    "@coreui/angular": "^5.2.14",
    "@ngrx/data": "^18.0.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^18.0.2",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^18.0.2",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^18.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^18.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^18.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.10"

This is my entity-metadata.ts file:
import {
  EntityMetadataMap,
  EntityDataModuleConfig,
} from '@ngrx/data';
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  Country: {}
};

const pluralNames = { Country: 'Countries' };

export const entityConfig: EntityDataModuleConfig = {
  entityMetadata,
  pluralNames
};

here is my app.config.ts
import {ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection, isDevMode} from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import {provideStore} from '@ngrx/store';
import { provideEffects } from '@ngrx/effects';


import * as fromApp from './store/app.reducer';
import {provideClientHydration} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideStoreDevtools } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

import {AuthEffects} from "./pages/auth/store/auth.effects";
import { provideRouterStore } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import {provideEntityData, withEffects} from '@ngrx/data';
import {entityConfig} from './entity-metadata';


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideStore(fromApp.appReducer, { runtimeChecks: {
            strictActionImmutability: true
        } }),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideEffects(AuthEffects),
    provideStoreDevtools({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),
    provideRouterStore(),
    provideEntityData(entityConfig, withEffects())
  ]
};

Even though I have providedIn: 'root' on this DataService it still isn't being invoked.
Here is my Custom DataService file:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {DefaultDataService, HttpUrlGenerator} from "@ngrx/data";
import {Countries, Country} from "../../../models/countries.model";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {map, Observable} from "rxjs";
import {baseUrl} from "../../../../../environments/environments";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CountryDataService extends DefaultDataService<Country>{

  constructor(http:HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator:HttpUrlGenerator) {
    super('Country', http, httpUrlGenerator);
  }



  override getAll(): Observable<Country[]> {

    return this.http.get<Countries>(baseUrl + '/api/country/GetCountries')
      .pipe(
        map(res => res["COUNTRIES"])
      )
  }
}

my resolver:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  Resolve,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CountryEntityService } from './country-entity.service';
import {CountryDataService} from "./country-data.service";
import {CountryActions} from './action-types';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CountryResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {
  constructor(
    private countryService: CountryEntityService
  ) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.countryService.getAll().pipe(map((countries) => !!countries));
  }
}


YOu could register the new service on the AppComponent which is the root of the application.
@Component({
    ...
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [ HeroDataService ] // <-- provide the data service
}) 
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    entityDataService: EntityDataService,
    heroDataService: HeroDataService,
  ) {
    entityDataService.registerService('Hero', heroDataService); // <-- register it
  }
}


You could also use the app_initializer method to initialize the service.
export function initializeApplication(entityDataService: EntityDataService, heroDataService: HeroDataService) {
  return (): void => {
      entityDataService.registerService('Hero', heroDataService); // <-- register it
  });
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideStore(fromApp.appReducer, { runtimeChecks: {
            strictActionImmutability: true
        } }),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideEffects(AuthEffects),
    provideStoreDevtools({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),
    provideRouterStore(),
    provideEntityData(entityConfig, withEffects()),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApplication,
      multi: true,
      deps: [EntityDataService, HeroDataService],
    },
  ]
};


Naren, thank you so much, that worked, man why didn't I think of that?  So as you mentioned I registered the Custom Service in my app.component.ts, one note,  the DataService file does require @Injectable({providedIn: "root"}) otherwise you get a null injection error.  Thanks again for your help.  = )

No Problem, thanks again
